# Team Members Team Utilities section in VS 2017

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

In **VS 2015** I had this that could install some check-in policies with it:

[image]

But in **VS2017** I can't find it. Where has it gone?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That came as part of the Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Power Tools. These haven't shipped for Visual Studio 2017.